# How to bind third party event to rxjs observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm using a third party text editor called froala in a project and for the keyup event I have to pass a callback function so I can get the value back from the editor. I'm trying to wrap the callback function in an observable somehow so I can use `debounceTime` but I can't get it to work right, here's some code:

in my component file:

```
export class EditorComponent
  editorOptions = {
    events: {
      'froalaEditor.keyup': (e, editor) => {
        do stuff here
      },
    }
  };
}
```

I tried to use this for the keyup event but it's not working because it's setting up a new observable for each event:

```
'froalaEditor.keyup': (e, editor) => {
  const text = editor.html.get();
  Observable.create(o => {
    this.service.updateData(data);
  }).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
    .subscribe();
}
```

what's the right way to make this work?

Comment: I think this will work for you: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindCallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a standalone [`Subject`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject) and push values into it, like:

```js
export class EditorComponent
  private onKeyup$ = new Subject();

  editorOptions = {
    events: {
      'froalaEditor.keyup': (e, editor) => {
        onKeyup$.next(e);
      },
    }
  };
}
```

**Important:** in this case you'll have to care about subscription completion by yourself. Search for proper observable completion in components for your particular framework.

**OR**

If you have a reference to the editor DOM node -- you could use [`fromEvent`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent) on froala event `froalaEditor.keyup` (see [froala docs](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events#keyup)).

E.g.

```js
const onKeyup$ = fromEvent(froalaDOMNode, 'froalaEditor.keyup');
```

In this case observable will complete once DOM node is destroyed, so you wont have to worry about unsubscribing manually.